# Opening a file when a user double clicks a file

Tags: macos, file-management

I am wondering how I use an Application bundle to open apps, and I am wondering how I have the following:

1. When I double click a file,
2. it opens up the application.
3. It sends the file path to a bash file

How do I do this?

Comment: [shebang!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're referring to may be explained in this Apple Developer article:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html